# Is space before colons in CSS valid in all browsers?

Tags: css

Is the following spacing convention valid in all browsers?

```
font-style     : normal;
font-weight    : normal;
font-variant   : normal;
```

Comment: spaces are spaces, browsers don't care which ones you use or if you even use any.

Comment: *All* browsers? probably not. The major ones people generally use? most likely yes

Comment: Note that space is a byte, so it adds eight to your file, you may want to keep the size lower by NOT doing this or minimizing before releasing to production...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html a CSS parser applies this regular expression for a declaration

> declaration : property S* ':' S* value;

You can insert `S*` spaces between the property and the colon (that means you can add `0` or any other amount of spaces). Note that the same rule is also applied between the colon and the value.

Generally speaking, if you look at the productions in the [CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) you can see how all the allowed spaces (the `S` symbol) are always followed by a `*` quantifier: so there's no a strict rule about the amount of spaces you can write.

This is also valid for [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/)